# How do I set auto increment field values to higher numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called `num` in SQL that I have initially auto incremented from 1. I know I can start the sequence from another value by using:

```
ALTER TABLE [myDatabase].[dbo].[myTable] AUTO_INCREMENT=500
```

Now what of the records that are already there. Is it possible to increase those `num` values? without deleting the records?

Comment: So you've somehow managed to get an `auto_increment` value less than the highest key value?

Comment: Did you try to `UPDATE` them?

Comment: so run the command then update the rows that are currently in?

Comment: You cann't do it with out delete records.

Comment: @bendataclear no. I am just wanting to start the number sequence at a higher number...and somehow increase the others

Comment: @lc. please explain update before running the command? because doing that will keep them at the same number.

Comment: Like `UPDATE myTable SET num = num + 42`? Some RDBMS might not let you update autogenerated IDs though.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, you have ID's `1, 2, 3, 4` etc, you want to update the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to 500 and set the records ID's to `500, 502, 503, 504` etc?

Comment: i get `Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot update identity column 'num'.`

Comment: @bendataclear that is correct

Comment: This is tagged mysql but I believe this is SQL Server...

Answer (score 0):

You can't update an identity column but you can move the data to another location, delete the original data then set identity_insert on and move the data back with the updated incrimentor.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create table for test
CREATE TABLE #MyTable ( Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Data INT )

INSERT INTO #MyTable ( Data ) VALUES ( 10 )
INSERT INTO #MyTable ( Data ) VALUES ( 20 )
INSERT INTO #MyTable ( Data ) VALUES ( 30 )

-- Store data in temp location
SELECT *
INTO #TempLocation
FROM #MyTable

-- Delete original data
DELETE #MyTable

-- Insert with updated id
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTable ON
INSERT INTO #MyTable ( Id, Data )
SELECT Id + 500, Data
FROM #TempLocation

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTable OFF
```